# focusing on a button on click

Tags: android, button, focus, onclick, drawable

Is it possible to  highlight or change the image of a button to another image Onclick() of a button ?

this is my xml for the button

```
     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:background="@drawable/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" 
    android:text="START" 
    android:focusable="true"
     android:id="@+id/start"></Button

>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, first get the reference of both buttons using `findViewById()` method, then do this

```
button1.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){

protected void onClick(View v){


button2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

}
});
```

**edit**

```
override another method.

button1.setOnFocusChangedListener(new OnFocusChangedListener(){

protected void onFocusChange()
{
button2.setBackground("your 1st image")
}
});
```

Comment: @drawable/button contains the image that i want to set as my background image for the button...and onclick of the button i want to show a change the image for a fraction to @drawble/red ..??? please help

Comment: okay .. fine when i do this i will be able to change the image completely ... and not revert back to the initial image ...

Comment: I want the second image to be there for a second and then revert back to the first  .. so it looks like its been clicked... thats all

Answer (score 0):

You can use setImageRessource method :

```
ImageButton.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){

protected void onClick(View v){


imageButton.setImageResource(R.id.newImage)

}
});
```

Comment: i tried using an image button .. but was not able to set text on the image button ... is it possible to set text in an image button??